# Sublime Text 3 overwrites manually installed package in OSX

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Following instructions to manually install arduino IDE [here](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino)

Reason for manual installation is because package manager has an older version of the plugin (10 months).

After placing it in ../Packages, I open ST3 and watch Finder. Initially, the folder extracted is named "Stino-new-stino". A folder is created at ../Packages/User/Stino with what seems to be options for the topmenu, and then the Stino-new-stino folder is deleted.

Tried to put extracted folder into ../Installed Packages, as well as ../Packages/User, but doesn't get detected.

Also noticed that my TomorrowTheme package got moved into my ../Packages/User/SublimeLinter.

I removed SublimeLinter and it still seems to be happening so I'm thinking it's an ST3 thing.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it might have to do with how the package is getting initialized via python script and might not be a Sublime issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some funky beta code happening and had to remove package-metadata.json for it to stop deleting itself.